# How to find the Q and P values in autocorrelation and partial autocorrelation plots?

Tags: time-series, data-science, advanced-custom-fields, forecasting, autocorrelation

[image]

From the above autocorrelatino plot i have to find the q for moving average model MA(q). What will be the value of q here?

[image]

Here, in this partial autocorrelatino plot what will be the value of p for autoregression model AR(p) ?

I have read many tutorials but i am confused how they are finding the values. I want to be clear about these two concepts. It will be a great help if i get some proper explanation. I took these two pictures from towardsdatascience article.